# Odoo / openerp:- subdomain based db_filter?

Tags: python, subdomain, odoo

I used subdomain as database name, so tried this.

My dbs:

```
dbs = test1, db1
```

So I tried this as

```
"test1.example.com", 
"db1.example.com"
```

Its working very well.

```
but i tried "demo.example.com" (there is no db named "demo", i know), it directs to "demo.example.com/web/database/manager".
```

Here I want show "demo.example.com" is not available insted of manage databases page. is there any way to achive this? please let me know...!